# jQuery modify CSS attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes

Trying to change background image when isEndOfGame becomes true, but it goes to the first image then just stays on that image. It console.logs "running" every second, but doesnt change the image.

```
    var endOfGame = {
        isEndOfGame: false,
        displayEndScreen: function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                if (endOfGame.isEndOfGame === true) {
                    console.log("running");
gameController.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, gameController.canvas.width, gameController.canvas.height);
                if ($("#canvas").css('background-image') == 'url(images/endOfGame.jpg)') {
                        $("#canvas").css('background-image', 'url(images/endOfGame1.jpg)');
                    }
                else {
                        $("#canvas").css('background-image', 'url(images/endOfGame.jpg)');
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    };

    endOfGame.displayEndScreen();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HENHD/1/

If someone can use that jsfiddle above with their own images (not sure if that's possible on jsfiddle) and try and see what's wrong, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: You can leave the `else if` part behind, it will return the same as the `else` statement.

Comment: You set isEndOfGame:false, then check it as true finally expect to run?

Comment: I have it displaying now but cannot make it change every 1 second. New code going up now.

Comment: try checking the `background-image` property instead of `background`

Comment: Thanks @koala_dev My canvas has had background as an attribute all through my game and worked. I modified it with this $('#canvas').css('background', 'transparent'); and it worked. And this works $("#canvas").css('background', 'url(images/endOfGame.jpg)'); I guess it is still worth a shot but would puzzle me as to why it has worked with background in the past if that was the issue. As of this new code, it makes the background the correct image, but never changes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change background image in css using,

```
$("#canvas").css('background-image', 'url(images/endOfGame1.jpg)');
```

Comment: thank you. I made my code the same but changed to background-image everywhere including in the css file. I called the code like this outside of any object or function and it displays the first image and then just stays on that image:

               
$(document).ready(function() {
endOfGame.displayEndScreen();
});

            I must just be calling it wrong. the setInterval portion of the code is not working. It displays once then doesnt change

Answer (score -3):

What is that attribute $("#canvas").**attr('background'**, 'url(images/endOfGame1.jpg)');?
May be must that - $("#canvas").attr('style', 'background:url(images/endOfGame1.jpg)');?

Comment: I just changed it to .css. I think .css is working in the same way. I should note that it is working because these images never get drawn to the canvas untill now, and this function makes it happen. it just doesn't change the image.